# Lifetime of Microsoft Extensions Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm currently writing a small wrapper with an interface around "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging".

Main reason for doing this is because I can't use FakeItEasy with extension methods like 'LogWarning'.

Here is a small sample:

```
public interface ILoggerWrapper<out T>
{
    void LogWarning(string message, params object[] args);
    void LogWarning(Exception exception, string message, params object[] args);
}

public class MicrosoftLoggerWrapper<T> : ILoggerWrapper<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger<T> _logger;

    public MicrosoftLoggerWrapper(ILogger<T> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void LogWarning(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning(message, args);
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering about the lifetime of this logger and what lifetime the "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" has. Is it a Singleton or Scoped?

How should I register my wrapper in the ServiceCollection? Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILoggerWrapper<>), typeof(MicrosoftLoggerWrapper<>));
```

Comment: It's singleton (proof: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

Comment: BTW, you don't need to mock extension methods. You need to mock only one method from `ILogger` interface - `void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter);`. All extension methods use this method so there is no point in mocking the extension methods.

Comment: ^ This. Mock the `Log` method. Easier that way, anyways. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is *already* a logging abstraction. Don't create a whole other one around it.